# Redis Daemon Script not working right

Tags: linux

I have this script for starting my redis server with init.d.  My problem is when it starts, it doesn't release the console. So when i do `sudo /etc/init.d/redis start`, it starts correctly, but it holds the command line. At the moment, I can't remember the characters needed to add to the end of the line to have it start in its own session (for lack of a better word)

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     redis-server
# Required-Start:   $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $syslog
# Should-Start:     $local_fs
# Should-Stop:      $local_fs
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    redis-server - Persistent key-value db
# Description:      redis-server - Persistent key-value db
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis.conf
NAME=redis-server
DESC=redis-server
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -x $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP || exit 0

set -e

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    touch $PIDFILE
    chown redis:redis $PIDFILE
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
    then
        echo "$NAME."
    else
        echo "failed"
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 10 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
    then
        echo "$NAME."
    else
        echo "failed"
    fi
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    ;;

  restart|force-reload)
    ${0} stop
    ${0} start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `/etc/redis/redis.conf` should contains `daemonize yes` instead of `no`.

Then ensure your init.d `PIDFILE=/var/run/redis.pid` is the same as your redis.conf `pidfile /var/run/redis.pid` and you are done!